# Unable to search based on filter value in react web app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

```
let tempArry = Data.filter(
    (item) => item.shipmentNumber.includes(props.dataToTable) 
    )
```

> input box : 578   expected result : 5788976641, 578897664, 5788976643
>
> input box : 578   actual result : 5788976648, 578897587, 7858976578
>
> I'm filtering an array of objects which by shipmentNumber on passing
> filter value from input box, check the expected and actual result .

Comment: Does the result contains only those that start with the search text?

Answer (score 0):

You should use indexOf instead of includes. Because includes returns true if the string is present in the testing string. No matter what the position is. You need to find the index of subString and see if the index is 0. That means the subString is at the beginning of the string.

```
let tempArry = Data.filter(
(item) => item.shipmentNumber.indexOf(props.dataToTable) === 0
)
```